# Adicionar opção em campo "sexo" do Magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento

Preciso adicionar uma opção no campo "sexo" escrito "neutro".

Sei que onde fica esses atributos no banco de dados é na tabela:  `eav_attribute_option_value`

Porém como adiciono um novo atributo lá para aparecer na opção sexo?